# Determine a scalar equation of the plane with the given vector equation, WITHOUT using cross product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Our professor has tasked us with solving these 4 questions (not-for-marks homework) WITHOUT using the cross product. I can only solve them with the cross product:

[image]

Here are the answers we're given:

[image]

Can anyone explain the process to solving at least 1 of these? I believe starting requires finding the normal vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can find a normal vector in some way other than the cross product, the rest can work out the same.

Looking at problem A31, we want a vector $\vec n$ which is perpendicular to $(2, 3, -1)$ and perpendicular to $(4, 1, 0)$. Since a dot product of non-zero vectors is zero if and only if they are perpendicular, that's equivalent to saying

$$ \left[\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 3 \\ -1 \end{array} \right] \cdot \vec n = 0 \qquad
\left[\begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] \cdot \vec n = 0
$$

The zero makes it easy to come up with vectors $\vec n$ satisfying the second equation: $n = (1, -4, n_3)$ works no matter what value $n_3$ is. Plugging that into the first equation gives $2 -12 - n_3 = 0$, so $n_3 = -10$, and we get the normal vector $\vec n = (1, -4, -10)$.

Note there are many valid vectors $\vec n$ solving the two equations, since multiplying $\vec n$ by any constant (non-zero) scalar gives another solution. But they will all give equivalent equations in the end, so we just need one particular $\vec n$.

To finish up A31, we know the equation of the plane is $\vec n \cdot \vec x = C$ for some constant $C$. Multiplying out this dot product,

$$ x_1 - 4x_2 - 10x_3 = C $$

Now we need any point on the plane. The easiest to find is by setting $s=t=0$; the point $(1,4,7)$ is on the plane. So the constant must be

$$ C = 1 - 4(4) - 10(7) = -85 $$

and an equation for the plane is

$$ x_1 - 4x_2 - 10x_3 = -85 $$

The same process will work for problems A32 and A33. A34 doesn't have the convenient zero coefficient to make things easier, so you'll need a little more work to figure out a solution to the equations

$$ \begin{align*}
n_1 + 3 n_2 + 2 n_3 &= 0 \\
-2n_1 + 4 n_2 - 3 n_3 &= 0
\end{align*} $$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first problem. Let's write the vector $\vec{x} = (x, y, z)$ in terms of its coordinates, and let's use different letters just to improve clarity. The vector equation is simply an equivalent formulation of the follow system of linear equations:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= 1 + 2s + 4t & (1)\\
y &= 4 + 3s + t & (2) \\
z &= 7 - s &(3)
\end{align}
$$
The goal is to eliminate the auxiliary variables $s$ and $t$ so that we get a single equation in $x, y, z$. For example, we can use $(1)$ and $(2)$ to eliminate $t$ first, so that $(1) - 4 \times (2)$ gives us $x - 4y = -15 -10s$, which we can call equation $(4)$. By combining $(4)$ and $(3)$ suitably, we can eliminate $s$.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that, and by isolating "s" I was able to get "z" to be 15/2, which, according to what we need the normal vector to be, should be -10. I added my work to my question via edits. Can you let me know where I went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewTrent you're assuming $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$, but that probably isn't a solution, and besides, you want and equation for all points $(x, y, z)$ in the plane.

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor How would I operate without the assumption (x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)? I'm lost with this question.

Comment: @MatthewTrent In your first step, for example, you'd have $4 t = x - 1 - 2 s$.

Comment: Also, multiplying by $4$ is not the same as multiplying by $4 / 4$.

Comment: Let's finish the rest of my solution. In order to use $(3)$ and $(4)$ to eliminate $s$, we can do $(4) - 10 \times (3)$: what this means is I consider equation $(4)$ and $-10$ times equation $(3)$, then I add the two equations together. This gives us $x - 4y - 10z = -15 - 10s -70 + 10s$, which is the same as $x - 4y - 10z = -85$. This is essentially the "first principles" of linear algebra -- solving simultaneous equations. (Note that there is no reference to the normal vector, which is a more "advanced" concept.)